# How to block external links from websites that have loaded our website in an iframe?

Tags: seo, google, backlinks, iframe, negative-seo

There's website [lilpot](https://lilipot.ir/) which has listed URLs to millions of website from it's domain and is loading those websites in iframe. Recently, it has started doing the same for my domain too. We want to remove these external links to our website to avoid any possible negative SEO implication. There are few solutions:

My observation: Links to website like amazon, walmart etc. is giving 404 error here - either lilpot has put wrong URLs here OR amazon has done something to avoid this.

1) Don't send any content if request referrer is of this website: This will not show our content on this website but I suspect Google will still see our website being linked from this domain and we will still see our links in google's external links to website list. Is this right thing to do?

2) Change my webpage to dis allow any website to load it as iframe - I got a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896623/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-to-be-loaded-via-3rd-party-site-frame-of-iframe) for this. Is this right thing to do?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about any possible negative SEO implication, you could disavow the links. See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en

Personally, I would be more concerned about the bandwidth loss. I'd combine your two options: Have your server send a small html page containing iframe busting JS instead of the real content if the referrer matches the lilpot domain.